# No Autoplay of mp3 file within jQuery.ready() on Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to automatically play an mp3 file when the browser opens a webpage. Here is my javascript code based on jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert("Hey");
    (new Audio('mp3/musik.mp3')).play();
});
```

Chrome on Android is newest version from Google Play store (50.0.something), on my Laptop it is 44.0.2403.157 (Ubuntu 15.10 64bit).

In both browsers the popup is showing, but the mp3 is only played on my laptop. If the same code (the one within the anonymous function) is executed by a onclick event, it works on both devices. This doesn't make sense, does it? Where the hell is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Auto-playing HTML5 audio is not supported Chrome Android, I think. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132

Comment: What @JohnSmith said. Except it's not a bug. It's a 'feature' of mobile devices preventing unnecessary downloads *without* user consent.

Comment: @Wainage Yes, as the article I linked stated. "This is intended. Autoplay is not honored on android as it will cost data usage."

Comment: Thanks @JohnSmith, your comment is actually the correct answer. Either you answer it on your own and get the credits or I will post the answer on my own to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnSmith for the anser within the comments of my question:

> Auto-playing HTML5 audio is not supported Chrome Android, I think.
>
> http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132

Answer (score 0):

.load can fail, see http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Use document .ready instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hey");
    (new Audio('mp3/musik.mp3')).play();
});
```

Comment: As I said: load() does not fail in my case, because on both browsers (Chrome on Android and Ubuntu) it fires. However, on Android only alert() is apparently executed, but Audio.play() generally works, e.g. via onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

Let me know if this works.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I've tried this and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        new Audio('Into the Wild - Red to Black.mp3').play();
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solved your issues.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer, this should solve your issues.

Comment: I've tested it on my android and I see what you mean, this has got to be some sort of a bug. The exactly same code that works on button click also executes on "load" event, yet the player won't start. I even simulated "click" event on load and it did not start playing the music. But when I clicked that exactly the same button, it worked. Somebody please make sense of this.

Comment: Please see the comments under my original question. This behaviour is intended for mobile devices.